# How to pass arguments to ViewModel's constructor at runtime using Hilt and Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm developing an app using Jetpack Compose and Hilt for DI. My ViewModel actually has a injected use case but I need to pass an extra argument at runtime. My composable view is a `ModalBottomSheet`. I need to pass this object to my view model in order to run a network call to fetch data based on object id.

Here is my composable view

```
@Composable
fun StopTimesMapScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    stop: Stop,
    onDismissListener: (() -> Unit),
    viewModel: StopTimesMapViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)

    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    ModalBottomSheet(
        modifier = modifier,
        onDismissRequest = onDismissListener,
        sheetState = sheetState
    ) {
        StopEstimations(status = uiState.status, estimations = uiState.estimations)
    }
}
```

And my view model

```
@HiltViewModel
class StopTimesMapViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val getStopTimesUseCase: GetStopTimesUseCase
): ViewModel() {

    private val _stop = MutableStateFlow<Stop?>(null)

    private val _estimations = MutableStateFlow<Resource<List<StopEstimation>>>(Resource.loading())

    val uiState: StateFlow<StopTimesMapUIState> = combine(_stop, _estimations) { stop, estimations ->
        StopTimesMapUIState(
            name = "${stop?.id} - ${stop?.name}",
            estimations = estimations.data ?: emptyList(),
            status = estimations.status
        )
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = WhileUiSubscribed,
        initialValue = StopTimesMapUIState()
    )

    fun loadStop(stop: Stop) {
        _stop.value = stop

        viewModelScope.launch {
            getStopTimesUseCase(stop.id)
                .collect { estimations ->
                    _estimations.value = estimations
                }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is to pass `Stop` object to VM's constructor so I can handle non-optional `Stop` flowable as well as call `loadStop` on `init`.

Comment: use Assisted Injection

https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html.

Comment: and try this https://medium.com/scalereal/providing-assistedinject-supported-viewmodel-for-composable-using-hilt-ae973632e29a